# How To Pick PDF Path from resources?

Tags: android, pdf, resources

I have pdf file that I need to store locally in the folder somewhere in the res/raw or assets.

Now I don't know which is the best folder to keep this file and how to pick path of it to display in third party application.

I am using following code that is not working:

**code:**

```
i = new Intent(this, Tips10.class);
                i.putExtra(PdfViewerActivity.EXTRA_PDFFILENAME, getResources()  +"/"+ getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.tips10);
                startActivity(i);
```

**log cat:**

```
03-10 00:33:04.335: I/PDFVIEWER(9473): Intent { cmp=com.tackfu/.Tips10 (has extras) }
03-10 00:33:04.335: I/PDFVIEWER(9473): ST='file 'android.content.res.Resources@410cc978/com.tackfu/2130968576' not found'
03-10 00:33:04.335: I/PDFVIEWER(9473): ST='reading page 1, zoom:1.0'
```

Any one guide me what could be the issue?
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will either need to copy the PDF to external storage and use that path with `startActivity()`, or you will need to create a `ContentProvider` that will serve the file from internal storage (or conceivably straight out of resources/assets, though that is a bit more difficult).

[This sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/ContentProvider/Files) demonstrates serving an internal file via a `ContentProvider`. [This sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/ContentProvider/GrantUriPermissions) extends the first one to only allow the app you specify to access that `Uri`.

Comment: but i am using open source library to open pdf inside my app still i need to copy that pdf taking out of resources and put on external storage?

Comment: @UMAR: You will have to ask the author of the open source library how to use it. I assumed that you were using a normal third-party application to view it, since that's what most developers would do.

Comment: all right i have implement this code and it works, but found a small exception in your code, you have not wrapped activity code in try catch block, so when suitable application is not installed in the phone/tablet your application crashes anyways thanks for your help :)

Comment: @UMAR: My sample definitely assumes the existence of a PDF viewer.